# SSHException: Channel closed

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using following code connect the RC (windows server) server via SSH library. when I am trying to execute command,

```
*** Settings ***
Library           OperatingSystem
Library           SSHLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    SSHLibrary.Open Connection    10.117.207.225    alias=ssh \
    SSHLibrary.Login    reutadmin    Reuters01    delay=1s
    ${stdout}    ${stderr}=    Execute Command    echo 'Hello John!'    return_stderr=True
    Should Be Empty    ${stderr}
    log     ${stderr}
```

Getting the following Error. Can you please help me on this case:

enter image description here    channel connection closed:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTSyu.png)

Comment: This error message means that the remote machine has closed the connection. You might have a look at any logs/messages on that machine, in order to understand why.

Comment: Hi Dominique, I  am getting the following error in the  server side. The description for Event ID 0 from source sshd cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

sshd: PID 5476: error: do_exec_no_pty: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: I am getting the this information as well , The description for Event ID 0 from source sshd cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

sshd: PID 5476: Accepted password for reutadmin from 11.31.211.138 port 56826 ssh2

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation, in my case the error happened during Login step.
The cause was `PermitTTY no` in sshd server configuration. It was setup to serve only SFTP, and without TTY robotframework failed to login.

Changed server configuration to `PermitTTY yes` (which is default) resolved the issue.